# How to copy a string to clipboard with ng-click in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to copy link on click button in `AnuglarJS`. I have tried below code but I have stucked in this error:

This is my `button` :

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="test2(\'' + decodeURI(data.name) + '\');" >copy</button>
```

this my function in `controller.js` :

```
  $scope.test2 = function (name)
    {            
        var res = 'http://example.com?from=' + name;
        var range = document.createRange();         
        range.selectNode(res); // here getting error
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        try {                
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            console.log('Copy email command was ' + msg);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
        }     
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }
```

click on button I want to copy this link any one can please help me how can do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [selectNode() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNode) `range.selectNode()` expects a param of type [node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNode) where your node is a string -> `var res = 'http://example.com?from=' + name;`.

> The Range.selectNode() method sets the Range to contain the Node and
>   its contents. The parent Node of the start and end of the Range will
>   be the same as the parent of the referenceNode.

Just create a dummy element for copy, append it to your DOM, copy it and remove it from DOM:

```
$scope.copyToClipboard = function (name) {
    var copyElement = document.createElement("textarea");
    copyElement.style.position = 'fixed';
    copyElement.style.opacity = '0';
    copyElement.textContent = 'http://example.com?from=' + decodeURI(name);
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.appendChild(copyElement);
    copyElement.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    body.removeChild(copyElement);
}
```

#### View

```
<button class="btn btn-info" 
        ng-click="copyToClipboard(data.name);">copy</button>
```

Comment: but here in my question how can do that please tell me.

Comment: range.selectNode() using this is not possible?

Comment: It's simply not needed.

Comment: but i am copy this link in the table data so i want to just click on button pass name and i have add link+name and pass res = "string" i want to like this. i am not used any text area,etc..

Comment: Yea, thats what you can do with this solution. Looks like you don't understand it. Added the view, hopefully you understand it now.

Comment: document.createElement("textarea"); this is i m not used so here i what is used?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. I just create hidden dummy element `textarea`, it's appended to your document, copy exec is fired, the element is removed after the copy exec was permitted -> done.

Comment: copyElement.css is not a function getting error in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139575/discussion-between-coderwill-and-lin).