# Copy to clip board is not working in JavaScript code but work on chrome console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, clipboard

in my code, i need to get key

**Html**

```
<div class="span3" ng-if="ec.name==='AccessTokenKey'">
  <input class="mTop10 span9" type="text" ng-model="token" id="encpText" />
  <button class="btn btn-alt btn-small " ng-click="encryptMD5Get()" title="Copy to clip board"><i class="fa fa-clipboard" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function copyToClipBoard() {
  // var text_to_share = "hello world";
  document.querySelector('#encpText').select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
}

$scope.encryptMD5Get = function() {
  var token = 'test Key';

  guidelineEditFactory.getEncryptionKey(token).then(function(response) {
    var EncString = response;
    $scope.token = EncString;

    setTimeout(function() {
      copyToClipBoard();
    }, 1000);

  });
}
```

In this code i am not getting copy in my (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>)
and there in (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>) old copy code which is copy by (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>)

but when i tried to do this on chrome console it will work 
so where i am doing wrong

Comment: Have you try to search before asking? This problem has been solved dozens of times.

Comment: yes tried but not getting where i am wrong

Comment: What about this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139185/how-to-copy-a-string-to-clipboard-with-ng-click-in-angularjs/43139397#43139397

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a string to clipboard with ng-click in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139185/how-to-copy-a-string-to-clipboard-with-ng-click-in-angularjs)

Comment: things are same when i use buttton ng click it not work
but on chrome console it is working

Comment: As you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/hj6f1bmf/ it does work as expected.

Comment: it looks like you are using a promise. Can you verify copyToClipBoard() is getting called for sure? you don't have a call back written in case the promise returns a failure

Comment: yes @Flemin Adambukulam copyToClipBoard() is called but copy to clipboard logic is not working
and if i use another button to  copyToClipBoard() code it will work fine
but not inside encryptMD5Get() function

Answer (score 2):

Use [ngclipboard](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/ngclipboard/)

Setup

First, include angularjs and clipboard.js into your document.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
```

Then Include ngclipboard.js.

```
    <script src="dist/ngclipboard.min.js"></script>
```

Add ngclipboard dependency to your module

```
    var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngclipboard']);
```

Finally, add ngclipboarddirective to the wanted html element.

```
    <button class="btn" ngclipboard data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn't mean you should — clipboard.js">
Copy to clipboard
```

**In Your Case**

```
<div class="span3" ng-if="ec.name==='AccessTokenKey'">
    <input class="mTop10 span9" type="text" ng-model="token" id="encpText"/>
    <input class=”hide-input” id="id" value={{token}}>
<button class="btn btn-alt btn-small link-btn" ng-click="encryptMD5Get()" title="Copy to clip board" ngclipboard data-clipboard-target="#id">Copy Clipboard</button>
```

Comment: from here i need $scope.token value so how do i get that $scope.token value

Comment: <button class=”link-btn” ngclipboard data-clipboard-target=”#id”>Copy Clipboard</button>
    <input class=”hide-input” id=”id” value={{token}}>